# How can I make a while loop only run a limited number of times?

Tags: python

In the code below, I'd like to run the function `roll()`, after: `deal = input("Your Turn: ")`, but only up to a limited number of cycles (52)

How can I achieve that?

```
import random

ydeal = random.randint(1,15)
adeal = random.randint(1,15)

yscore = 0
ascore = 0

def roll():
    if deal == "Deal":
        print(ydeal, adeal)
        if ydeal > adeal:
            yscore + 1
        elif ydeal < adeal:
            ascore + 1
        print(yscore, ascore)

deal = input("Your Turn: ")
roll()
```

As a side note: I noticed that when printing `yscore` and `ascore` the value does not change during the loop, how can I fix that?

Comment: The issue is that, unlike a help desk, the Q & A are meant to serve a wider audience than just the poster. combining questions into one make them harder to find, making your question useless for others with the same problem.

Comment: when you enter `roll` you check if `deal == "!"`. if you insert a number as an input the program crashes, and if you insert any other string the program exists OK. Anyway, I do not really understand your purpose.

Comment: I want a point added to the scores to whoever number is higher that the other. If its an equal number add no point to each of the players' scores.

Comment: Look up the python built in command `range()`

Comment: Thanks @RolfofSaxony

Comment: @IMAGO I am afraid you're not quite getting the concept of SE sites.

Comment: Exchanging...anyways how do I put function roll() in a loop 52 times? Just answer please!

Comment: Done, in a generalized manner.

Comment: Thanks @JacobVlijm

Comment: @JacobVlijm There is no reason for you to keep telling him(IMAGO) his question is off-topic for SO. If the question really is off-topic, then it will eventually get deleted, closed, or migrated.

Comment: @Mr.goosberry I think the question is quite on topic actually, but multiple questions in one is an issue generally :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about your code, but you can limit the number of loops by adding one to `n` on each loop, and use `while n <= 52` (or any other value):

```
n = 1
while n <= 3:
    word = "monkey" if n == 1 else "monkeys"
    print(n, word)
    if input("press Return to increase the number of monkeys ") == "":
        n += 1

print("\nOoops, we ran out of monkeys...")
```

Then:

```
1 monkey
press Return to increase the number of monkeys 
2 monkeys
press Return to increase the number of monkeys 
3 monkeys
press Return to increase the number of monkeys 

Ooops, we ran out of monkeys...
```

In your situation:

```
n = 1
while n <= 52:
    deal = input("Your Turn: ")
    roll()
    n += 1
```

However, your function `roll()` isn't quite working as it should:

- your `ydeal` and `adeal` are fixed values, and won't change during the game.
- whatever you do with your variables *inside the function* has no effect outside, unless you set the variable to be `global`, or you make the function return something.

An example:

```
test = 5

def add_one(var):
    return var + 1

test = add_one(test)
print(test)
> 6
```

but that is another question :).

Comment: @IMAGO what do you mean by that?

Comment: I want it to randomize Numbers after deal. So a random Numbers would be, 5 and 8. 8 is higher so 1 point is added to ascore. And this goes on for 52 loops?

Comment: @IMAGO if you set `while n <= 52:`, then, yes, whatever you put in your loop will run 52 time. randomize, run, whatever.

Comment: @IMAGO absolutely, since the loop will run `while n <= 52` (smaller or equal to), starting from 1.

Comment: I done one part, the roll() needs fixing. So is there no way to Koop functions liked this, 'while roll() = 5'?

Comment: @IMAGO the function `roll()` will never return `5`, since it returns nothing actually as it is. It only alters some things *inside the function* for as long as the function runs, after that, the "world is unchanged".

Comment: I've completed may program thx to u. I didn't know a variable wouldn't change outside the function.

Comment: @IMAGO You're welcome! It always makes me happy if it works out :)

Answer (score 0):

I noticed a couple of problems in your code:

1. Inside the `roll()` function you have to declare that you want to use the global variables and not two new variables that are local to the function,
2. You are not assigning the increment to the value. A correct way to do it is: `yscore += 1`.

At the end, I report to you a reviewed version of your code. At the end of the code I have inserted a 52 iterations while loop example.

```
import random

ydeal = random.randint(1,9)
adeal = random.randint(1,9)

yscore = 0
ascore = 0

def roll():
    #Notify that the variables you want to use are not defined inside the function
    global yscore
    global ascore
    if deal == "!":
        print(ydeal)
        print(adeal)
        if ydeal > adeal:
            yscore += 1
        elif ydeal < adeal:
            ascore += 1
        print(yscore, ascore)

deal = input("Your Turn: ")
roll()

#while loop
max_iteration = 52
counter = 0

while counter < max_iteration :
  counter += 1
  print ("while: ", counter)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think ute misunderstood, i should've explained. I want a score added to one of the score variables for whoevers number is bigger that the other. I want this same process to repeat for 52 times.

Comment: Just move the while loop where necessary ;)

Answer (score 0):

I support Jacob's answer that you can limit the number of loops by adding one to n on each loop, and use while n <= 52 (or any other value). I also read many programming tips at http://ubuhanga.com and I think they can also help you

Comment: English site link? 

Answer (score 0):

How about this using `range` as per my comment

```
import random

def ydeal():
    return random.randint(1,15)
def adeal():
    return random.randint(1,15)

yscore = ascore = draw = 0

def roll():
    global yscore, ascore, draw
    if deal == "Deal":
        for x in range(52):
            yydeal = ydeal()
            aadeal = adeal()
            if yydeal > aadeal:
                yscore += 1
            elif yydeal < aadeal:
                ascore += 1
            else:
                draw += 1
            print("Score:", yscore, ascore, draw)

deal = input("Your Turn: ")
roll()
```

Note: using python2.7 you would need to change `deal = input("Your Turn: ")` to `deal = raw_input("Your Turn: ")`

Answer (score 0):

Here my previous suggestion with the while loop in the correct place:

```
import random

yscore = 0
ascore = 0
max_score = 52;

def roll():
    #Notify that the variables you want to use are not defined inside the function
    global yscore
    global ascore
    if deal == "!":
        while (yscore < max_score and ascore < max_score) :
            ydeal = random.randint(1,9)
            adeal = random.randint(1,9)
            print(ydeal)
            print(adeal)
            if ydeal > adeal:
                yscore += 1
            elif ydeal < adeal:
                ascore += 1
            print(yscore, ascore)

deal = input("Your Turn: ")
roll()
```